# Rounding value in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am creating description label in which i want my description label height should be depend on the value rounded from the expression

```
    NSString *description = [dic objectForKey:@"des"];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8];
    CGSize desSize = [description sizeWithFont:font];
    float hgt = desSize.width / userView.frame.size.width;
```

i want the value of hgt should be exact number like if value of output is 0.1 then it should give me value of hgt as 1, another like if value of o/p of devision is 3.3 then hgt should become as 4.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ceil()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/) to round up.

```
float hgt = ceil(desSize.width / userView.frame.size.width);
```

Answer (score 3):

you want to use `ceil()`. that will round the number up to the nearest integral number.

Answer (score 1):

```
fabs() – Find the absolute value or unsigned value in parentheses.
result = fabs(x); // fabs(-2.5) = 2.5

ceil() – To round up
i = ceil(x); // ceil(3.5) = 4

floor() – find the integer that is below the floating point value.
i = floor(x); // floor(4.2) = 4

pow() – raise a number to the power.
i = pow(x,y); //pow(4,2) = 16

sqrt() – Square root of a number.
i = sqrt(x); // sqrt(16) = 4

exp() – find the expoential value.
```